# Subreport rotate 90 degree

Tags: rotation, jasper-reports, subreport

Can I rotate my subreport 90 degree as you can see in the picture? There will be not only text field. The goal is to rotate all subreport.

[image]

Comment: You can rotate the text inside of the subreport.

Comment: @TomaszIwaszko But you can not rotate the whole subreport

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research and I found that there is no possibility to rotate whole subreport. The only way is to rotate texFields and images.

http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/4647#comment-816396